# Show data dynamically in line chart - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I need to show some data in my line graph in my Angular 6 app, after a certain amount of time, so lets say each 333ms to show some data. I am displaying data registered in max 30 sec, so every graph data can last maximum of 30 seconds. It has to start on a button click.

Here is some test data I created just for testing purposes:

```
test_data = {
        '222': {
            joy: 66.5057373046875,
            fear: 1.0003513832343742,
            anger: 2.000018799044483,
            disgust: 3.004251452162862,
            sadness: 4.0001135088386945,
            contempt: 5.001299204188399,
            surprise: 6.203749045729637
        },
        '238': {
            joy: 97.06363677978516,
            fear: 17.500137131541123,
            anger: 27.00000593749519,
            disgust: 6.001324078417383,
            sadness: 21.000043172625737,
            contempt: 21.00033742573578,
            surprise: 32.62530106306076
        },
        '722': {
            joy: 66.5057373046875,
            fear: 60.000351383234374,
            anger: 70.00001879904448,
            disgust: 10.004251452162862,
            sadness: 92.0001135088387,
            contempt: 40.0012992041884,
            surprise: 50.20374904572964
        },
        '838': {
            joy: 97.06363677978516,
            fear: 15.000137131541123,
            anger: 64.50000593749519,
            disgust: 24.501324078417383,
            sadness: 31.500043172625737,
            contempt: 18.50033742573578,
            surprise: 6.2048268765211105
        },
        '1722': {
            joy: 66.5057373046875,
            fear: 54.000351383234374,
            anger: 72.00001879904448,
            disgust: 0.004251452162861824,
            sadness: 80.0001135088387,
            contempt: 20.0012992041884,
            surprise: 20.203749045729637
        },
        '2838': {
            joy: 95.37223815917969,
            fear: 41.000168004859006,
            anger: 62.00000752212509,
            disgust: 33.001674098544754,
            sadness: 3.000052563053032,
            contempt: 44.00044780407916,
            surprise: 4.204549819231033
        },
        '2839': {
            joy: 98.75503540039062,
            fear: 1.0001062582232407,
            anger: 1.0000043528652895,
            disgust: 1.0009740582900122,
            sadness: 2.000033782198443,
            contempt: 2.0002270473924,
            surprise: 1.2051039338111877
        }
    };
```

Here, these values '222', '238' etc, are milliseconds where these values need to be shown in the graph. I structured this data so I have arrays like this:

```
joyArray = {
    data: [66.5057373046875, 97.06363677978516, 66.5057373046875, 97.06363677978516, 66.5057373046875, 95.37223815917969, 98.75503540039062],
    label: '',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 217, 40, 1)',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    fill: false
};

// push all arrays into this array to show it on the graph
this.chartData.push(this.joyArray, this.fearArray, this.angerArray, this.disgustArray, this.sadnessArray,
            this.surpriseArray, this.contemptArray);
```

and so on, for every object property.

My graph is implemented like this:

```
<canvas id="chartCanvas"></canvas>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

So I need to click on a button and show these values for each frame (222ms, 238ms...), anyone has an idea how to do this using chartJS?

**EDIT:** changed the structure of arrays, now it is an object with data inside. Draw chart function looks like this:

```
drawChart() {
        this.chart = new Chart('chartCanvas', {
            type: 'line',
            data: this.data,
            options: this.options
        });
    }
```

Data object:

```
data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [] // datasets = this.chartData;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
test_data = {
    '1222': {
        joy: 66.5057373046875,
        fear: 1.0003513832343742,
        anger: 2.000018799044483,
        disgust: 3.004251452162862,
        sadness: 4.0001135088386945,
        contempt: 5.001299204188399,
        surprise: 6.203749045729637
    },
    '2238': {
        joy: 97.06363677978516,
        fear: 17.500137131541123,
        anger: 27.00000593749519,
        disgust: 6.001324078417383,
        sadness: 21.000043172625737,
        contempt: 21.00033742573578,
        surprise: 32.62530106306076
    },
    '3722': {
        joy: 66.5057373046875,
        fear: 60.000351383234374,
        anger: 70.00001879904448,
        disgust: 10.004251452162862,
        sadness: 92.0001135088387,
        contempt: 40.0012992041884,
        surprise: 50.20374904572964
    },
    '4838': {
        joy: 97.06363677978516,
        fear: 15.000137131541123,
        anger: 64.50000593749519,
        disgust: 24.501324078417383,
        sadness: 31.500043172625737,
        contempt: 18.50033742573578,
        surprise: 6.2048268765211105
    },
    '5722': {
        joy: 66.5057373046875,
        fear: 54.000351383234374,
        anger: 72.00001879904448,
        disgust: 0.004251452162861824,
        sadness: 80.0001135088387,
        contempt: 20.0012992041884,
        surprise: 20.203749045729637
    },
    '6838': {
        joy: 95.37223815917969,
        fear: 41.000168004859006,
        anger: 62.00000752212509,
        disgust: 33.001674098544754,
        sadness: 3.000052563053032,
        contempt: 44.00044780407916,
        surprise: 4.204549819231033
    },
    '7839': {
        joy: 98.75503540039062,
        fear: 1.0001062582232407,
        anger: 1.0000043528652895,
        disgust: 1.0009740582900122,
        sadness: 2.000033782198443,
        contempt: 2.0002270473924,
        surprise: 1.2051039338111877
    }
};

var arr = Object.entries(test_data)


var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["joy", "fear", "anger", "disgust", "sadness", "contempt", "surprise"],
        datasets: []
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    reverse: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}




var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var myC = new Chart(ctx, options);


arr.forEach((v) => {
    setTimeout(() => {


        myC.data.datasets.push({
            data: [v[1].joy, v[1].fear, v[1].anger, v[1].disgust, v[1].sadness, v[1].contempt, v[1].surprise],
            label: "#" + v[0] + "Milisec"
        });
        myC.update()
    }, parseInt(v[0]))
})
```

```css
canvas { background-color : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Hmm, it is close, but what I need is a little different, now you drew the entire line after some period of time. What I need is to show each of these objects in test data after that many miliseconds - example: after 1222ms show first object, after 2328 show 2nd object... So the graph has some flow, like a video, you go through seconds and show emotions

Comment: use something like this example : https://jsfiddle.net/therowf/jp48kb5L

Comment: I am not sure how to structure my data like the data you provided in this example :/

Answer (score 0):

I understand  you want to update view with new fresh json data every xx ms 
in summary you need to :

- have a service which exposes a shared observable, say data$;
- the service has the method to fetch the remote data and update the shared observable above, say getRemoteData()
- that service Observable.interval() which calls the method to fetch the remote data
- have your component that displays the data
- have the component subscribe to the data observable from the service.

the next sample code illustrates how to implement it

```
import {takeWhile, first} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from "rxjs";
import { PositionsModel } from "./positionsmodel";
import { MouvementService } from './mouvement.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mouvementview',
  template: '<div *ngIf="data"> your chart </div>',
})

export class MouvementviewComponent implements OnInit {
  public data: PositionsModel;
  private display: boolean; // whether to display info in the component
                            // use *ngIf="display" in your html to take
                            // advantage of this
  private alive: boolean; // used to unsubscribe from the IntervalObservable
                          // when OnDestroy is called.
  results : string;
  // Inject mouvementService
  constructor(private mouvementService: MouvementService) {
    this.display = false;

    }

ngOnInit() {
   this.mouvementService.getPositions().pipe(
      first()) // only gets fired once
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.data = data;
        this.display = true;
        this.alive = true;
});

// get our data every subsequent 200 mseconds
interval(200).pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive)) // only fires when component is alive
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.mouvementService.getPositions()
          .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;
          });
      });

}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.alive = false; // switches your IntervalObservable off
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I tried doing something similar but it didn't do the job for me :/ Not sure how to implement your code with my data structure honestly, I would need to show first value of each array of emotions for every frame, not sure how to do it like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chart.js's  `addData()` function with a setTimeout method for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Add data</title>
         <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div class = "container">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>            
        </div>
        <script src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            addData(myChart, "White", 7);
        },3000);

        function addData(chart, label, data) {
            console.log(console.log(chart.data.datasets[0].data));
            chart.data.labels.push(label);
            chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data);
            chart.update();
        }
```

Hope this could be helpful. You can change setTimeout to setInterval if you prefer adding data to the chart in intervals (such as every 2 secs).